# How do I traverse LWC DOM and find the email and phone links

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, dom, shadow-dom

I am trying to see how I am able to find email and phone links within the LWC DOM. I am well aware that it is shadow DOM so I did try to detect the shadow root inside my BFS implementation
Here is the code sample

```
  findLinksInSFDC: function (component) {
    const links = [];
    const queue = [document.documentElement];
    while (queue.length > 0) {
      const node = queue.shift();
      if (node.tagName === "A") {
        const href = node.getAttribute("href");
        if (href && (href.startsWith("tel:") || href.startsWith("mailto:"))) {
          links.push(node);
        }
      }

      if (node.shadowRoot) {
        queue.push(node.shadowRoot);
      }

      if (node.children) {
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
          queue.push(node.children[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return links;
  }
```

When I got to the point at "one-record-home-flexipage2", everything stops. Although I inspected the element and confirm that it has shadowRoot property, but when I tried to print it, it returned null.

This helper method [findLinksInSFDC] is used in `rerender` in the renderer.

Comment: I suggest that you are trying to do something you simply should not be doing and there's probably a better way to do it. Why are you doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This seems like an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: We have our custom emailing and calling tool implemented in the utility bar. We want clicking on the phone and mail links open the tools instead of the Application on the computer.